# Is there a way to find out ETA of the process running on another terminal?

Tags: command-line

I executed a tar command to uncompress a compress folder. It was a 9GB and it has taken like 47 minutes right now and still running.

Is there any way I can find out how much time it will still be running?

Comment: Do you know the uncompressed size of the folder?

Comment: I know I should have paid attention to that, But I didn't .

Answer (score 2):

You can get statistics by sending a "signal signo" to the process.

From [the GNU tar manual, 3.7 Checking tar progress](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_25.html):

> You can also obtain this information on request. When `--totals` is
>   used with an argument, this argument is interpreted as a symbolic name
>   of a signal, upon delivery of which the statistics is to be printed:
>
> ```
> --totals=signo
> ```
>
> Print statistics upon delivery of signal *signo*. Valid arguments are: `SIGHUP`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. Shortened names
>   without `SIG` prefix are also accepted.

Comment: nice, but how does that give an ETA if the compression ratio is unknown?

Comment: The only way is to make a guestimate from the status info. The other way is to start to make a contribution to tar to add that feature.

Comment: Could you describe how to guess the ETA from the output of --totals?

Comment: Read what the signal does!

Comment: Yes, it prints something like `Total bytes written: 424335360 (405MiB, 25MiB/s)`. How can I calculate an ETA from that without knowing the compression ratio?